# How can I loop this if statement when I call a function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to call the `boss[i].showBoss()` and `.moveBoss()` functions every time the counter is 10,20,30,40...(dividable by 10), ( `if(counter % 10 === 0)` works only when the counter is at a number divisible by 10, not the others), but this hard-coded example only runs the code once after `counter == 10`, not when `counter == 20,30,40` etc. Any suggestions on how I can can start the functions every time `counter % 10 == 0`, but not stop them after the counter is not `% 10`, for instance 11?

```
   function draw() {
    // put drawing code here
    background(220);
    if (counter >= 10) {
      for(i = 0; i < boss.length; i++){
        boss[i].showBoss();
        boss[i].moveBoss();
      }
    } else if (counter >= 20) {
      for(i = 0; i < boss.length; i++){
        boss[i].showBoss();
        boss[i].moveBoss();
      }
    } else if (counter >= 30) {
      for(i = 0; i < boss.length; i++){
        boss[i].showBoss();
        boss[i].moveBoss();
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: First of all your not checking that its divisible in your if statements, just that they are greater than equal to. Also we need to know where your calling this function, as that is the important part. I don't have the full picture but I would recommend that whereever the counter is updated you invoke the function.

Comment: `if (counter % 10 == 0)`

Comment: Your own suggestion `counter % 10 === 0` works for every number divisible by ten, not just ten itself. Did this not work when you tried it?

Comment: I am calling the functions for boss

Comment: What do you mean you are calling the function for boss ? @Mr.Ulis

Comment: If no ones answer here yet has solved your problem, please redefine your problem in more detail and elaborate on your desired out comes! @Mr.Ulis

Comment: boss[i].showBoss and boss[i].moveBoss are the two functions that i want to call, and i want to call them by using a if statement, where they start going when the counter i dividible by 10, but dont stop after its not (the functions are basically a ball going down the screen slowly, but i dont want it to stop when counter == 11)

Comment: So your saying you want the ball to move for all counter values over 10 ? In javascript `counter >= 10`?

Comment: No, i want the ball to move for ever after it has started, but it a new ball i drawn every time i the counter is dividable by 10 a new time. (counter % 10 == 0 (10) -> a ball starts and goes on forever, counter % 10 == 0 (again, 20) -> a new ball spawns and goes on forever.) sorry for bad grammar here

Comment: Ahhhh okay! So the 'boss' object is the ball ? And every time `counter % 10, counter % 20, counter % 30, etc` is true you want a new ball to get created and move forever ?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: Okay okay that helps. Yea you have a much large probably here that just these if statements. Im worried that I don't see a `new` keyword or anything like that. Where are you creating these new balls?

Comment: I have a class called Boss, and showBoss() and moveBoss() are functions inside that class. I call them in this draw function that automatically draws the balls for me. I create the balls in a function called setup, that i linked to the Boss class.   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    boss[i] = new Boss(100 + i * 200,-20,35);
  }

Comment: I just need to know how i can start a new boss ball every time counter is dividable by 10, and not stop that ball form running after counter is not dividable by 10. Maybe boolean is the awnser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object to represent your boss action you want to start. When divisible by 10, create one of these and added to a list of bosses to draw. Every draw loop, draw all your bosses.

```
let bossesToDraw = [];

function draw(){
  if(counter % 10 == 0){
     bosses.push({
        // state for the boss like its current position
        // this could also create a new boss if you have a proper object
     });
  }
  bosses.forEach(function(boss){
    boss.showBoss();
    boss.moveBoss()
  });

  //maybe check if you should remove the boss
}
```

Comment: what do i push in the bosses.push() method?

Comment: @Mr.Ulis A newly created boss. It sounds like you want a boss to be created every 10 counts. So when the count is divisible by 10, we create a boss and add it to the collection of bosses. Every interval, we iterate over all bosses we’ve created (those stored in bosses) and animate them

Comment: You haven’t shown the code for the boss or how they’re created which is why I had to leave the bosses.push with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of answering your own question here...

Can't you just do:

```js
function draw() {
    // put drawing code here
    background(220);
    if (counter % 10 === 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < boss.length; i++) {
            boss[i].showBoss();
            boss[i].moveBoss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, as i tried to explain, it works to an extent, however the function stops running when the counter is not dividable by 10, which i dont want.

Comment: My code above calls `showBoss`, and `moveBoss` "`boss.length` times" every time that the counter is wholey divisible by 10. what other functionality are you needing? I am missing the rest of your requirements

Answer (score 0):

The function `draw()` will run anyways. What you need to do is to check when your counter is divisible by 10, your instruction `counter % 10 === 0` works fine for that.. Here I've mimic the draw function behaviour with a `setInterval`. Please note that the draw function is now an arrow function, that's to have access to the counter variable in the scope. This is irrelevent in your case.

```js
let counter = 0;

let draw = () => {
  // we do normal draw things
  // background(255);
  if(counter % 10 === 0) {
    // we need to animate the boss.
    console.log('current counter was divisible by 10', counter);
  }
  
  counter  ++;
};


setInterval(draw, 100)
```